# Error in Compilation of PL/SQL Function

Tags: oracle, plsql

[image]

[image]

When I try to run the function shown in image 1, I receive the error in image 2. I'm new to PL/SQL so please help me. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Are you sure you're working in T-SQL at all? That command prompt looks oracle-ish, whereas T-SQL is the *dialect* of SQL spoken by Microsoft and Sybase SQL Servers. And the code you've shown doesn't look like T-SQL dialect.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I learnt T-sql before so since pl/sql and t-sql seem a bit similar to me, I thought I can call pl/sql as t-sql. my bad! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check "CREATE" keyword is mssing check the syntax here [CREATE FUNCTION (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx)

Comment: Its not T-SQL, By looking on variable naming conventions

Comment: @simplify_life thanks.. my bad! I didn't read my lecture until the end!!

Comment: @Maddy heehee.. yes. It's pl/sql :D

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to simplify_life(If you are not creating this function in a Package Body, If yes create is not required)

Update Statement is invalid:

**Correct:**

```
Update Department set budget = budget_limit....
```

**Wrong:**

```
Update Department set budget := budget_limit ....
```